# tbl_replace forbidden in phpmyadmin

Tags: centos, centos5

On CentOS 5 I updated phpMyAdmin to the latest release. I can access and browse tables and records but when I try to insert a new record I receive the following error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/tbl_replace.php on this server.
```

- I used `chown -R apache:apache do phpmyadmin dir`
- I then used `chmod 775 -R to  phpmyadmin dir`
- I then tried reverting back to the old phpMyAdmin release 2.11.x and I get the same error.

How can I track down the problem and solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found it was a conflict with mod_security